# Is it possible to set the backgroud of a QTableWidgetItem as no-repeat?

Tags: image, qt

I am trying to put images into one of the column in my table (QTableWidget). However, so far I cannot find a way to make the image no-repeat.

I cannot set the width of the image to fit the cell, because the images are some barcode and will not be scanned after stretching.

I had tried to use setStyleSheet on QTableWidget, but has no effect on individual cells.

Is it even possible to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I think what you need to do is use QTableView instead of QTableWidget and then inherit a class from QStyledItemDelegate and then override the paint method:        void QStyledItemDelegate::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const [virtual]......to draw your pixmap

Comment: and also to set the size of a particular cell you need to override sizehint method

Comment: Thank you. So that means there is no simple built-in API for this.

Comment: No,there is no direct method to do so